# How to setup a development system for a web application?

Tags: development-environment

Currently I am working with a Perl based web application which is quite big (~ 100.000 LOCs; created by one single developer) and is permanently in use with quite a lot of requests per day (several 100.000). It is a private project and the expection of the owner is a continuous operation of the production environment (PE).

Surprisingly, when I took over the system there was no test/development environment. Fortunately, most of the changes/extensions I created so far were quite small and, consequently, the risk of (unplanned) downtimes or collisions with the user's work were marginal.

But now bigger changes are in sight and I wanted to setup a DE to avoid all the hassle connected with development on a production system.

From my point of view the biggest challenge are the domains and the access to them. My requirement is that I/we access all domains of the DE via the same domain names which are used by the production system (domain names are hard coded in the Perl code). The DE should be accessible over the internet as the PE is currently (password protectio for the DE should be implemented of course).

Currently the system resides on a single VPS with Apache as the web server and a MariaDB as the database.

My idea to get the diversion to the respective system to work was to make use of a reverse proxy (nginx), which decides to which of two servers (one bearing the DE, one the PE) the requests should be diverted (maybe on the base of the (dynamic) IP adresses of the development clients (Windows or Mac)).

The criterion for the choice of the target could be submitted via ssh from the clients to the proxy immediately before the start of work. But I have no idea how to update this information without restarting the web server (which is desirable).

Are my ideas feasible or are there (possibly simpler) implementations?

Comment: **domain names are hard coded** - well I think that's the first thing you should address, move all hard coded URLs, domain names, database connection strings etc into some kind of configuration file and have the application read them from that file. Have two different configuration files, one for production and one for development and just deploy the correct one for each environment.